# Binance.Net getting historical data from start date to end date loop optimization

Tags: c#, performance

I'm using [Binance.Net](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net) and I wanted to get historical candle data from start date to end date which is useful for backtesting. They don't really provide that functionality, so I have to do it myself. [Their API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data) allows me to specify `startTime` (start date) and `endTime` (end date) and limit (cannot exceed 1000). I'm reading candles until I reach all of them between `start date` and `end date`, because of that limit.

#### Two test cases (read the comments right next to `first` and `last`):

I added them to the question so you can get the idea behind that REST point.

```
BinanceClient client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions()
{
    ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(configuration["BinanceSettings:ApiKey"], configuration["BinanceSettings:SecretKey"]),
    AutoTimestamp = true,
    AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});

var candles = _client.GetKlines(symbol: "TRXUSDT", interval: KlineInterval.ThirtyMinutes, startTime: new DateTime(2018, 06, 06), endTime: new DateTime(2020, 06, 16), limit: 1000).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList();

// Test case 1
var first = candles.First().OpenTime; // 6/11/2018 11:30:00 AM. This doesn't match the specified "startTime" because Binance doesn't have data before the returned date
var last = candles.Last().OpenTime; // 7/2/2018 6:00:00 PM. This doesn't match the specified "endTime" because the limit is 1000, which means it cuts the result when it reaches 1000.

// Test case 2
var candles = _client.GetKlines(symbol: "TRXUSDT", interval: KlineInterval.ThirtyMinutes, startTime: new DateTime(2020, 06, 06), endTime: new DateTime(2020, 06, 15), limit: 1000).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList();
var first = candles.First().OpenTime; // 6/6/2020 12:00:00 AM - fine
var last = candles.Last().OpenTime; // 6/8/2020 8:00:00 AM - That's the latest data, because the specified "endTime" is greater than the current date and time.
```

#### Something very important:

That loop's only responsibility is when there are more than 1000 candles between a given start date and end date. For example if the start date is `2018-01-01` and end date: `2020-01-01` (2 years), assuming the interval remains 30 minutes (`KlineInterval.ThirtyMinutes`), there are going to be way more than 1000 candles, which means a single call to `client.GetKlines(...)` won't make it. It will return the first 1000 candles but not all of them. If the period between start date and end date is very short, we might end up with less than 1000 candles returned by `client.GetKlines(...)`, which is fine. It might be better if I add a check to the loop (execute it only if the first call to `client.GetKlines(...)` returns 1000 candles; if less - do nothing).

#### The actual question:

I believe my code works fine and covers both test cases from above. Can you suggest me what to improve for better visual and performance look? A parallel loop would be a way to add multithreading in order to execute it faster.

```
// Input data
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 04);
DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 01, 15);

// Logic that has to be improved
var interval2 = KlineInterval.OneDay;
var candles = _client.GetKlines(symbol, interval2, startTime: StartDate, endTime: EndDate, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();
var firstCandle = candles.First();
var lastCandle = candles.Last();

while (true)
{
    var candles2 = _client.GetKlines(symbol, interval2, startTime: lastCandle.OpenTime, endTime: EndDate, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();

    firstCandle = candles.First();
    lastCandle = candles.Last();

    // This check prevents re-adding already existent data
    if (candles2.Last().OpenTime != lastCandle.OpenTime)
        candles.AddRange(candles2);

    if (EndDate == new DateTime(lastCandle.OpenTime.Year, lastCandle.OpenTime.Month, lastCandle.OpenTime.Day) || EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
        break;
}

foreach (var candle in candles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(candle.OpenTime);
}
```

Comment: How many candles do you actually get (I would expect 255 (2018-06-04 to 2019-01)?

Comment: @JanDotNet, from `new DateTime(2018, 6, 4)` to `new DateTime(2019, 1, 15)` = 219 candles. That's because Binance has data from `6/11/2018`. So the start date is actually `new DateTime(2018, 6, 11)`.

Comment: Ok, but 219 is less than the limit of 1000. Why do you have to load the candles in multiple steps?

Comment: The limit is 1000. It cannot return more than 1000 candles but it can return less. The reason I do that in a loop is because if the candles between `start date` and `end date` exceed 1000, which is the limit, it won't collect them entirely but just the first 1000.

Comment: @JanDotNet, I hope you get the idea. If we look at the example above (`startTime: new DateTime(2018, 6, 4) ` and `endTime: new DateTime(2019, 1, 15)`), it doesn't have to go through the loop, because `client.GetKlines(...)` will return less than 1000 candles (219 - as we saw). It would probably be a better idea to add a check if `client.GetKlines(...)` returns `candles.Count = 1000` => do not process the loop, because that loop's only responsibility is when we have more than 1000 candles between `startTime` and `endTime`. 1000 is the maximum amount you can specify, if you look at their API.

Comment: Parallel processing helps with CPU-bound bottlenecks, like calculating a lot of cryptographically expensive hashes for example. Looks like the slow bit in your case is calling the API, which is IO-bound issue. Typically you'd solve that by using async calls, but it looks like you have to wait for each response before you can make the next request.

Comment: @StewartRitchie, yes https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/blob/b1023bb46b8f35f699f0c1195cbc6b37070a31c0/Binance.Net/BinanceClient.cs#L521. Which makes no difference.